# How to add n number of columns to an existing table,the new columns should have the aggregate of an existing column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table like:

```
ID NAME SALARY
1  JOSE 100
2  KEVI 100
3  JAMS 200
4  SANJ 400
```

I need to get the output like:

```
ID NAME SALARY SALARY-1 SALARY-2 SALARY-3 SALARY-4 
1  JOSE  100   99       98       97       96
2  KEVI  100   99       98       97       96
3  JAMS  200   199      198      197      196
4  SANJ  400   399      398      397      396
```

How can I get the desired table?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want output, then use a query:

```
select id, name, salary, salary-1, salary-2, salary-3, salary-4
from table t;
```

If you actually want to add these columns to the table, you can use `alter table add column` and then update the values.

Comment: Thanks .... But what if i want N number if columns, 60-70 columns,and 1000's of employees ?

Comment: @user3304713 If you want to have N number of columns then you should use stored procedures.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks Deepak .... Any idea can u put up ? I am new to stored procedures.

Comment: @user3304713 Please check the stored procedure i have posted. this is working for me.

Comment: Thanks its a great job,Its working fine .... Is it possible to save it to a new table or existing table?... so i could take it out from MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

Use this stored procedure to get your result. This is working for me.
Please change the table and column name as per your db.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_proc$$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(n INT)
proc : BEGIN

SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT ID, NAME, SALARY');
SET @num = 1;

select_loop : LOOP

    SET @q = CONCAT(@q, ', SALARY - ',@num);

    IF n = 0 THEN
        LEAVE select_loop;
    END IF;

    SET n = n - 1;
    SET @num = @num + 1;

END LOOP;

SET @q = CONCAT(@q, ' FROM sal');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Call the stored procedure with the number of salary columns you want in output

```
mysql> CALL my_proc(4);
+----+------+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | NAME | SALARY | SALARY - 1 | SALARY - 2 | SALARY - 3 | SALARY - 4 | SALARY - 5 |
+----+------+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | jose |    100 |         99 |         98 |         97 |         96 |         95 |
|  2 | kevi |    100 |         99 |         98 |         97 |         96 |         95 |
|  3 | jams |    200 |        199 |        198 |        197 |        196 |        195 |
|  4 | sanj |    400 |        399 |        398 |        397 |        396 |        395 |
+----+------+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks its a great job,Its working fine .... Is it possible to save it to a new table or existing table?... so i could take it out from MySQL...

Comment: i don't have enough reputation for voting the answer .... when i get, i surly will .... your answer was helpful:-)